# How do I calculate the opposite side of an angle that is at an angle.

Tags: geometry

I would like to calculate the length of the hypotenuse of a triangle that is the extended of an other triangle, but at a certain angle.

Original triangle: BAC
adjacent side : AB = 30,4
hypotenuse : BC
Opposite side: AC

B angle : 16

Extended triangle: DBE

adjacent side : BD
hypotenuse : BE
Opposite side: DE

Triangle AED
adjacent side : DE
hypotenuse : AE
Opposite side: AD
E Angle : 10

So I would need length BE

[image]

Comment: I can calculate everything within the original triangle BAC, but have trouble with DBE. Im not sure anything in BAC will help me with DBE

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/YOkYBEx.png

Maybe I can use the triangle ACD to get the length of AD. But I do not think I can get an angle for that triangle.

Comment: Do you know the sine rule? Apply that to triangle BAE.

Comment: @Jaap, BAE is not a right triangle though

Comment: The [sine rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) applies to any triangle.

Comment: @Jaap I only knew of the basics of sin! I looked it up and it seems to work out!

I calculated BE with the sine rule sin(64)/30 = sin(16)/x

Then I calculated AD with sin,and then DE with pythagoras and then BE with pythagoras!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Another option is to drop altitude BF to AE, then $BF=BE \sin BEA=AB\sin BAF$. $\angle BEA$ and $\angle BAF$ can be found easily.